# Increase width of columns

Tags: tables

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0.65 in,bottom=0.65 in,left=0.65 in,right=0.65in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    %\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Question                & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10            \\\hline
        Answer                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Question: How can i increase width of columns in my table?

Comment: One way would be to increase the `tabcolsep`: For example, `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}`.  Highly recommend you have a look at the `booktabs` package and its associated documentation regarding tables.

Comment: @PeterGrill  if yo don't mind, would you correct my codes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a length explicitly or use `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0.65 in,bottom=0.65 in,left=0.65 in,right=0.65in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Set a length explicitly:

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|*{10}{C{.4in}|}}
        \hline
        Question                & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10            \\\hline
        Answer                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}

Or use \texttt{tabularx}:

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{10}{Y|}}
        \hline
        Question                & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10            \\\hline
        Answer                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

This is just to show the canonical way to typeset tables with \texttt{booktabs}, as suggested by Peter Grill:

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*{10}{Y}}
        \toprule
        Question                & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10            \\
        \midrule
        Answer                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* one way to set the column height is to use 
`\setcellgapes` and
`\makegapedcells` by `makecell`, for other methods see here: [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0.65 in,bottom=0.65 in,left=0.65 in,right=0.65in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{.1in}

\begin{document}

Set a length explicitly:

\begin{center}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|*{10}{C{.4in}|}}
        \hline
        Question                & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10            \\\hline
        Answer                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}

Or use \texttt{tabularx}:

\begin{center}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{10}{Y|}}
        \hline
        Question                & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10            \\\hline
        Answer                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

This is just to show the canonical way to typeset tables with \texttt{booktabs}, as suggested by Peter Grill:

\begin{center}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*{10}{Y}}
        \toprule
        Question                & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10            \\
        \midrule
        Answer                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, didn't see you had `booktabs` as well. If you want to mention the `tabcolsep`, I can delete my answer.

Comment: No, please, leave your answer, but see my comment under it

Comment: lenght? or length?

Answer (score 4):

You can make the columns wider by increasing `\tabcolsep`.  Here is a before and after version of your table with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}`:

[image]

Also, I would recommend you look at the `booktabs` package and the associated documentation. Here is an minimal example as your table doesn't really have any data:

[image]

### Notes:

- I removed the `{center}` environment as one should be using `\centering` instead. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/4301).

  As CarLaTeX mentioned, with the MWE given in the question, it is ok to use the `{center}` environment (as it does not use the `table` environment). However, most will be using the `table` around `tabular`, so thought it should be pointed out.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
 Question & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline 
Answer & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline 
\end{tabular}  

\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
 Question & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline 
Answer & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline 
\end{tabular}  
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

### Code: `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcccccccccc} 
\toprule
Question & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
%\cmidrule(lr){1-11}% <-- Not very useful here.
Answer & & & & & & & & & & \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your help.

Comment: special thanks for kind attention to my question.

Comment: One should not use `center` environment within a `table` environment, but alone it's OK.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I had just assumed that the `table` environment was used :-(. You should make a note of that point in the linked question's comments.

Comment: @PeterGrill Done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508243/101651!